# linq to sql or Entity framework when you are most of the time going to call database using stored procedure?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I'm working on a project where most of the times I'm going to call database with a stored procedure and I'm a little bit confused what should I do. Options are not just restricted to Sql to Linq and EF. If there are any better options please suggest them too.

**UPDATE - Reason for using SPs**
I've to apply logic in many of the stored procedure. Apart from this, my intention to use SPs for CRUD operation is to improve performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM tools wasn't designed to be used only with stored procedures (but they could), it will be very difficult to map data on eneities and perform all operations using EF. You can relay on [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx), but I need some details to suggest something more meaningfull.

Comment: What kind of more details you need?

Comment: Your typical operations to perform with SP, CRUD or all? Do you have any option do not use SP's or you just forced to perform all operations this way?

Comment: I've to apply logic in many of the stored procedure. Apart of this my intention to use SPs for CRUD operation is to improve performance.